# repeated errors saving files and folders onto external hard drive. after errors harddrive becomes read only

Tags: permissions, mount, backup, external-hdd

I am having problems with my external hard drive.  It has been going on for weeks.

I just turned off my computer. Then I typed *mount*. The result was

/dev/sda1 on /media/michaeo/MY_EXTERNAL_DRIVE Data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)

Next, I try to copy files only the external. I get an error

When I type *mount* again, I get

/dev/sda1 on /media/michaeo/MY_EXTERNAL_DRIVE type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)

I am not surprised that the externall hard drive is now read only. I get that because if there are errors then this is what is supposed to occur.

The problem is that I need to backup my data. This has been going on for weeks and I am not sure what to do.

**My question:**

What to do about this?

Have I been hacked?

Maybe my hard drive has errors?

Maybe a port has errors?

Comment: Try fsck on your external drive. See [How to use the fsck command on linux?](https://www.howtogeek.com/745921/how-to-use-the-fsck-command-on-linux/) or something similar.

Comment: You write "I get an error" but neglect to mention what error it is that you get. Please edit your question to include the actual error message, and the Ubuntu version you are running. You may also have a look at the output of the `dmesg` command for kernel error messages referring to the `sda` disk.

Comment: If errors keep occurring after fixing them with fsck, install the smartmontools package and see what the disk reports:sudo smartctl -s /dev/sda